# Dropdownlist for not binding to model property mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

MVC3 DropdownListFor not binding the model property to selected value
Here is my View

```
@{var items = new List<SelectListItem>(){
                            new SelectListItem {Text = "2", Value = "2", Selected = true},
                            new SelectListItem {Text = "3", Value = "3", Selected = false},
                            new SelectListItem {Text = "4", Value = "4", Selected = false},
                            new SelectListItem {Text = "5", Value = "5", Selected = false}
                        };

        }   
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.InvoiceItem.Count, new SelectList(items, "Value", "Text"))
```

InvoiceModel has a property called InvoiceItem class which further has property Count of int type.
The count property is always 0 and is not being updated to the value selected from dropdown.

Please help I have already spent hours on this. Thank You.

---

Thank You for the responses. But I still have the issue.

I used 
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.InvoiceItem.Count, new SelectList(items, "value", "text", 2))

also tried @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.InvoiceItem.Count, new SelectList(items, "value", "text", "2"))

Count property is always 0. What am i missing here.

Comment: I wanted to make sure my question is clear, the dropdownlist has default value 2 selected, but when I save it, the model property which is associated to the dropdown is not set to 2. It is always 0.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
new SelectList(items, "value", "text", selectedvalue);
```

Ex:

```
@{var items = new List<SelectListItem>(){
                                new SelectListItem {Text = "2", Value = "2"},
                                new SelectListItem {Text = "3", Value = "3"},
                                new SelectListItem {Text = "4", Value = "4"},
                                new SelectListItem {Text = "5", Value = "5"}
                            };

            }   
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.InvoiceItem.Count, new SelectList(items, "Value", "Text", 2))
```

Comment: any further suggestions please. i am stuck here.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your problem is the same as mine. Please check whether `x.InvoiceItem.Count` is a property or a field. If it is a field, post data won't bind to it.

**My model**

```
public class SearchReportObject
{
    public string report_type;
}
```

**In cshtml**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.report_type, new SelectList( new List<Object>{new { value = "0" , text = "Red"  },new { value = "1" , text = "Blue" },new { value = "2" , text = "Green"}} , "value", "text"))
```

On post form, `report_type` always has a value of `null`. But when I change `report_type` from a field to a property like this:

```
public class SearchReportObject
{
    public string report_type{ set; get; }
}
```

It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

It is because current value of Model.InvoiceItem.Count (first argument in DropDownListFor) is overriding selected value in your SelectList.

It is that way so that your view model current value could be use to set this value after model error.

Solution to this problem was already posted by Cyberdrew, you have to use third parameter of SelectList constructor, which represents default selected value:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.InvoiceItem.Count, new SelectList(items, "Value", "Text", 2))
```

Comment: I wanted to make sure my question is clear, the dropdownlist has default value 2 selected, but when I save it, the model property which is associated to the dropdown is not set to 2. It is always 0.

Comment: I was using a <select> tag but the data wasn't binding, even though I specified what it was for. I changed it to this Html helper and the data binded. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I was not posting the dropdownlist to the controller in the save button click event.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are really sending the actual form to the server or if you are sending custom JSON data via AJAX or something like that.

It took me a while to finally realise my form was not being sent directly to the server, and that the "save" button actually was making an AJAX request. So, the fix was to set the select field value in a new property in the JSON data.

Thinking about it now, the select element value was being correctly binded all the time. It was just not being sent the way I thought it was.